# Phonegap eclipse environment on Mac OS

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, cordova

Are there any tutorials for creating an iPhone App on Mac OSx with Eclipse and [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)?

I have read many tutorials, but all of them were with Xcode without Eclipse. I would like to use the same code base and build for Android and iPhone from the same editor and test it on different devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, without any crazy work arounds, this would be very hard to achieve.  The base app (the PhoneGap) part of the code, is unique to iPhone and Android, this objective c, and java.

You probably need to use the separate IDE environments.

Comment: Really? Ufff what a shi*t. I will extra buy me an Mac OS computer and now I need to develop in different IDE's . Is there no possibility to make both in Eclipse?

Comment: Why can't you run both IDEs on the same computer?  I run both xcode and eclipse (as well as several other IDEs) on one computer.

Comment: Well of course I can. But because I will make the app with Phonegap I thought I can start fast the simulators and test the changes. In other way I need to switch every time the IDE's. Is it possible at least to use the same codebase, or not? Some tutorial for this?

Comment: It maybe difficult to have the same code base, but you could fake it with something like this: http://www.bananica.com/Geek-Stuff/Synchronize-two-folders-on-a-Mac-with-Automator-and-Rsync/  Basically, you have separate folders, but when a change occurs in one, the folders are synced.  I would look into automator scripts.

Answer (score 1):

you can find some plugin for eclipse, like: [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)

so now you can develop for iPhone (objective c) and for Android (java)

I read about it but I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Well I need to develop in JavaScript.